# B2C redirect failing to include client_id when code is copied from sample to project

Tags: javascript, msal.js

This is Vue.js 3.2.13, msal-browser 2.30.0 (installed package, not CDN), B2C interaction code adapted from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa

All of our code passes linting and building without error, but when attempting to sign in via B2C the B2C login form that appears in the popup says
**Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'.**

The body of the request is assembled by the msal-browser code, so it's not clear why this is happening or what to do about it. This does not happen when we run the example code with our own B2C details substituted. So it must be something we've inadvertantly changed in adapting it to our own project, but we can't spot it. As far as we can see the only difference is that we've installed the **@azure/msal-browser** package rather than including a **script** element pointing to the CDN.

The only interaction between our Vue.js project and the authentication code we copied from the sample is a call to **signIn()** on a **click** event in the UI. This is the call into the **msal-browser**-defined object:

```
const myMSALObj = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)

...

function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

As you can see, we haven't modified that call at all from the sample. We did try calling **loginRedirect()** in place of **loginPopup()**, with the same result. This is the definition of **loginRequest**, also unmodified from the sample:

```
const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", ...apiConfig.b2cScopes],
}
```

where the only change was putting our own scope into the **b2cScopes** array. Here's the definition of **msalConfig** (and we have verified that the values here are all present and correct at the point the **PublicClientApplication** constructor is called):

```
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        authority: authority,
        knownAuthorities: [authority]
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case Msal.LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message)
                        return
                    case Msal.LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message)
                        return
                    case Msal.LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message)
                        return
                    case Msal.LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message)
                        return
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And again, you can see **clientId** is there, exactly as it is in the sample code, just with our own value assigned.

Comparing the payloads between the request/redirect generated by the working sample project and the code transferred to our project, the only difference is that in our project the client_id value is missing; all other keys are the same, and have values. Why is that **clientId** property not being translated to a **client_id** value in the request body? Is there possibly some environmental difference that matters that we just don't know matters?

UPDATE: Just to eliminate the possibility we tried removing the package and adding a script element with `src="https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.30.0/js/msal-browser.min.js"` and the behavior is the same - that is, the **client_id** key has no value in the request or redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be tied to the fact that the one change we did make, and forgot to look into at first because it seemed so innocuous, was adding explicit exports and imports of some of the objects defined in the sample code, since they were not otherwise visible among each other once we moved the code to our own project. The **msalConfig** object defined in **authConfig.js** is not imported as the same simple object, but *as a default object with **msalConfig** as a property*. So this

```
import msalConfig from "@/auth/authConfig"
```

means that this

```
const myMSALObj = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig)
```

has to be replaced with this

```
const myMSALObj = new Msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig.msalConfig)
```

though of course the outer object can be imported with any name we like, and we did change it to **authConfig**.

Once that change was made the hand-off to B2C auth works as expected.